# Android AlarmManager elapsedTime fires wrong

Tags: android, alarmmanager, elapsedtime

Ok, so I'm setting an alarm:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
```

where

```
long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mynterval;
```

I'm saving `triggerTime` for comparison in future.
**And sometimes `alarm` is firing before `triggerTime`!**

For example, I can see in logs:

```
scanTime: 702672466
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime: 702672132
```

What delta error is possible here - 1 second, 2-3 seconds or more?
And why is this happening?

Comment: what Android version you are testing with?

Comment: If I use `setExact()` - then device with 5.1.1; if earlier devices - I use `set()` method instead.

Comment: Allright, see my answer about the Doze mode. Anyway the delta is in second (worst case) much more it will be in millisec

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to [Android Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

> If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode. In Doze mode, the system attempts to conserve battery by restricting apps' access to network and CPU-intensive services.

Now, alarm is the case of CPU-intensive services. As you can see in the image the intensive jobs are done together in so-called maintenance windows.

[image]

Standard AlarmManager alarms (including `setExact()` and `setWindow()`) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.
Alarms set with `setAlarmClock()` continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Comment: Interesting that device is plugged to pc and screen is on during that error. And due to that mode it would be possible that alarm would fire after triggered time. But in my case alarm is firing before.